# How to retrieve java Set and iterate over the values from response of ajax call?

Tags: javascript, java, json, ajax

I have following ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "../targeturl",
    data : postdata,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(response, status, request) {
    ** in response im getting three sets which i wish to iterate
     }
```

last few lines of controller methods are as follows:

```
JsonWrapper response = new JsonWrapper();
/*some lines to fetch data from db*/
response.addParam("vSet",vSet);
response.addParam("dSet",dSet);

return response;
```

Since I have never tried this before, please tell me know how to perform this. also let me know if question is not clear enough.

Comment: Please provide the proper code of the controller. Are you using some framework or plain servlets?

Comment: How the response `JSON` looks like?

Comment: @Luiggi, im using spring mvc.method returns JsonWrapper's obj.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **JQuery** :

```
$.each(response.vSet, function(index, element) {
    //process 
});
```

Using **Javascript** :

```
for(var i=0;i<response.vSet.length;i++){
  //process 
}
```

Comment: it should be `response.vSet.length` not `response.data.vSet.length`

Comment: second one worked for me after doing above mentioned change.

Answer (score 1):

If your response is valid Json, you can parse the response using javascripts built in function JSON.parse(). Then iterate over it as you like, depending on how you constructed your json in your response.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "../targeturl",
    data : postdata,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(response, status, request) {
        var json = JSON.parse(response).
        //iterate over json by accessing the indices of json.
        for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++)
        {
            (..) //do stuff with json[i]
        }
        //or access json using the key values you specified in your response
        json['vSet'] // or json.vSet.

        console.log(json) //this will allow you to inspect your response after you parsed it to json.
     }
```

Comment: i think it should be `var` instead of `int` in for loop.

Comment: also it becomes more complex if we use your solution and the response has more than one collections like in my case, it does.

Comment: How do you mean it becomes more complex? I'm not doing anything different than the other answer. He somehow expects response to be already in an object format having a 'data' property. I don't see why that would be the case, so I parse it to json first.